# how to select target file location javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my web application, i need an input type which opens a dialog box and allows user to select a target location to save a file. Can anyone please tell me how to do that in java script or jquery? or suggest me if any plugins or third party scripts that solves my requirement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the related source code.

Comment: Hi Vadim Landa! Thank you for your response. I am using like <input type="file" directory>. from this i'm able to get folder name but not absolute path. I know due to security issues, browser wont allow it from client machine. My question is can we get if we use external resources?